# svn diff and invalid option: --summarize"?

Tags: svn, diff

I run this command from the command line:

```
svn diff -r 90:93 URL --username name --password password --summarize
```

It keeps telling me that --summarize is unknown. Why? I searched the net and its being used. It works without --summarize, but I only need the paths, not the full info.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it say "--summarize is unknown" or "svn: invalid option: --summarize"?

Comment: It says: invalid option: --summarize"

Comment: Try
   
    svn diff  --summarize -r 90:93 URL --username name --password password

Comment: Its version 1.3.2 ... its not supported propably? It came with the 1 Click Setup from tigris (http://svn1clicksetup.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The `--summarize` option [was added on 1.4.0](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.4.html#new-switches). Subversion 1.3.2 is actually quite old ([it was released on 2006](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=445&dsMessageId=743026)).

**Update:** The [SVN 1-Click Setup](http://svn1clicksetup.tigris.org/) project looks abandoned. If you want to set up a Subversion server on a Windows-based computer, you'll probably prefer [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/).